# Como poner un boton de usuario con opciones desplegables en Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un sistema en NetBeans en el cual tiene usuarios y en la pantalla principal quiero poner un boton donde este la imagen del usuario y que al presionarlo se despliegue un menu que contenga la opcion de cerrar sesión. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo una solución parecida, pero con un JLabel en lugar de un botón.

Puedes hacerlo con el control Swing `Popup Menu` en la categoria de `Swing Menus` de la paleta, 
Arrastralo y ponlo en tu formulario se agregara en la categoría de `Other components` Hazle click derecho y coloca tu puntero en `Add From palette` y selecciona `Menu item` selecciona ese menu item y en la pestaña de propiedades, busca la propiedad `label` y escribe lo que quieres que diga esa opción, luego al Menu item que agregaste dale click derecho >> events >> Action >> actionPerformed. ahi escribiras tu código para cerrar sesión.

para hacer que aparezca al darle click derecho al label harás lo siguiente: click derecho sobre el label >> events >> mouse >> mouseReleased. ahi escribiras este código:

```
if(evt.isPopupTrigger())
{
     TuPopupMenu.show(evt.getComponent(),evt.getX(),evt.getY());
}
```

se vera de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y listo, ya tienes el menú al darle click derecho a la foto de usuario.
espero que haya sido de ayuda :)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido de mucho!

Comment: De nada :) Recuerda que cuando una respuesta haya resuelto tu problema marcarla como correcta y puntuarla :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que queres hacer es bastante sencillo, si estas utilizando Swing, podes usar un ComboBox, que es un menu desplegable.
[Aca](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) esta la documentacion del mismo.

Leela, y si te queda aluna duda, no dudes en preguntarla.

Comment: Si lo intenté con un combobox colocandolo a un lado de la imagen del usuario, pero el problema es que se muestra un item a lado de la flecha y solo quisiera que se muestre la flecha para que despliegue las opciones